# undefined local variable or method error when trying to use `instance_variable_set` in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a class like this

```
require 'net/http'
class Foo
  def initialize
    @error_count = 0
  end
  def run
    result = Net::HTTP.start("google.com")
    @error_count = 0 if result
  rescue
    @error_count += 1
  end
end
```

And this is a spec file for it.

require_relative 'foo'

```
describe Foo do
  let(:foo){ Foo.new}
  describe "#run" do
    context "when fails 30 times" do
      foo.instance_variable_set(:@error_count, 30)
    end
  end
end
```

And run `rspec foo_spec.rb`, then fails with this error.

```
foo_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `foo' for #<Class:0x007fc37410c400> (NameError)
```

How should I call `instance_variable_set` method in rspec?

*Edit*

I want to call `send_error` method if 30 times fails.

```
require 'net/http'
class Foo
  def initialize
    @error_count = 0
  end
  def run
    result = Net::HTTP.start("google.com")
    @error_count = 0 if result
  rescue
    @error_count += 1
    send_error if @error_count >= 30
  end
  def send_error
  end
end
```

And spec file to test that `send_error` is called when connection fails 30 times.

```
require_relative 'foo'

describe Foo do
  let(:foo){ Foo.new}
  describe "#run" do
    context "when fails 30 times" do
      it "should send error" do
        foo.instance_variable_set(:@error_count, 30)
        expect(foo).to receive(:send_error)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to do, but I suspect it's not the right approach to do things.

However, your immediate problem is that you're not in the context of a test, so `foo` is undefined. You want to wrap your `foo.instance_variable_set` in a test construct - either an `it` or `specify` block, or a `before :each`, or something similar.

Comment: I can use now `instance_variable_set`, thanks! I'd be very grateful if you tell me how should I test in situation like this. I added a little more code to my question.

Comment: I wouldn't use an instance variable in your model - I would wrap it up with an `attr_accessor`. In the test, I would then simply stub the method `error_count` on the object to return the value you want.